# HTML required readonly input in form

Tags: forms, html, google-chrome, readonly, required-field

I'm making a form. And on one `input` tag is an `OnClick` event handler, which is opening a popup, where you can choose some stuff, and then it autofills the `input` tag.

That input tag is also `readonly`, so only right data will be entered.

This is the code of the `input` tag:

```
<input type="text" name="formAfterRederict" id="formAfterRederict" size="50" required readonly="readonly" OnClick="choose_le_page();"  />
```

But the `required` attribute isn't working in Chrome. But the field is required.

Does anybody know how I can make it work?

Comment: `required` is a attribute new in HTML5 - it is still not supported in all browsers

Comment: You should mark your question with the HTML5 tag and Chrome tag

Comment: @Muleskinner: It's supported by the stable versions of Firefox, Chrome  and Opera: http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Comment: @Blender, thanks for the website, i bookmarked it right away :D

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I had same requirement as yours and I figured out an easy way to do this.
If you want a "readonly" field to be "required" also (which is not supported by basic HTML), and you feel too lazy to add custom validation, then just make the field read only using jQuery this way:

**IMPROVED**

form the suggestions in comments

```
<input type="text" class="readonly" autocomplete="off" required />

<script>
    $(".readonly").on('keydown paste focus mousedown', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode != 9) // ignore tab
            e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Credits: @Ed Bayiates, @Anton Shchyrov, @appel, @Edhrendal, @Peter Lenjo

**ORIGINAL**

```
<input type="text" class="readonly" required />

<script>
    $(".readonly").keydown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I also added a paste handler to preventDefault, and the solution was complete!

Comment: Good answer, but his blocked **ALL** keys (included Tab, Left, Right) and not blocked `Cut` event. I wrote self version :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Kanak your answer was useful for me.

Comment: Please note that this solution doesn't quite work for number inputs. You can still use the arrow keys to change input.

Comment: The fix for number input is adding a 'mousedown' handler.

Comment: @appel, in my case I needed the mouse click event, but I could use type="text" with pattern="[0-9]*". Anyway its a nice catch worth pointing out. thanks

Comment: @KanakSinghal Gotcha! I needed mine to be `type="number"` so I could use `min="100"` and `required` and have client side validation work (which it will not with the `readonly` attribute).

Comment: Beware the autocompletion. Add `autocomplete="off"` on the input or with jQuery: `$(".readonly").attr("autocomplete", "off")` or `$(".readonly").prop("autocomplete", "off")` for jQuery >=1.6.

Comment: I added the focus handler to avoid autocomplete and showing the cursor.

Answer (score 34):

`readonly` fields cannot have the `required` attribute, as it's generally assumed that they will already hold some value.

Comment: And you don't know an work around? because i want to check it before the form is realy submitted...

Comment: @TWCrap if your input field is read only how do you suppose your user gonna enter any value in that ??

Comment: @yogi, if you readed the question right, then you saw that i use on OnClick event handler that will popup something that sends an value back...

Comment: Well, aside from making some validation to ensure that the value is only one of those you are entering using your JS, there's little you can do. Also, I'd recommend using `onfocus`, for the use of tabs on your form.

Comment: @yogi with a datepicker modal . . .

Comment: Yeah datepicker modal is the obvious use case, `readonly` because it's the only way to stop a mobile device's keyboard popping up unnecessarily.

Answer (score 27):

Remove `readonly` and use function

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="id" required onkeypress="return false;" />
```

It works as you want.

Comment: can not handle delete content when backspace button it clicked.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the cursor ? maybe focus on some else? is it possible ?

Answer (score 21):

`Required` and `readonly` don't work together.

But `readonly` can be replaced with following construction:

```
     <input     type="text"
                onkeydown="return false;"
                style="caret-color: transparent !important;"                   
                required>
```

1) `onkeydown` will stop manipulation with data

2) `style="caret-color: transparent !important;"` will hide cursor.

3) you can add `style="pointer-events: none;"` if you don't have any events on your input, but it was not my case, because I used a `Month Picker`. My `Month picker` is showing a dialog on click.

Comment: Thank you, thats a simple solution.

Answer (score 16):

This is by design. According to the [official HTML5 standard drafts](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-readonly-attribute), "if the `readonly` attribute is specified on an input element, the element is [barred from constraint validation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#barred-from-constraint-validation)." (E.g. its values won't be checked.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a workaround for this issue. I found it from https://codepen.io/fxm90/pen/zGogwV site.

Solution is as follows.

**HTML File**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" required data-readonly />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS File**

```
input[data-readonly] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty neat. What do you know about the browser support for this css trick?

Comment: This doesn't prevent anyone from tabbing into the field and typing some text.

Comment: @cyanbeam - Couldn't you add a tabIndex of -1?

Comment: I suppose you may. I guess my point is that whatever you do to disable changing the field seems hack-ish and not semantically correct anyway.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone wants to do it only from html, This works for me.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" required />
```

Comment: A simple solution that simply works. 

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help.

```
<form onSubmit="return checkIfInputHasVal()">
    <input type="text" name="formAfterRederict" id="formAfterRederict" size="50" required readonly="readonly" OnClick="choose_le_page();"  />
</form>

<script>
     function checkIfInputHasVal(){
        if($("#formAfterRederict").val==""){
             alert("formAfterRederict should have a value");
             return false;
        }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for your template:

`<input required onfocus="unselect($event)" class="disabled">`

And this for your js:

```
unselect(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.currentTarget.blur();
}
```

For a user the input will be disabled and required at the same time, providing you have a css-class for disabled input.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer @KanakSinghal but without blocked all keys and with blocked `cut` event

```js
$('.readonly').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46)  // Backspace & del
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('keypress paste cut', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="readonly" value="test" />
```

P.S. Somebody knows as `cut` event translate to `copy` event?

Answer (score 1):

**Required and readonly don't work together**.

**Although** you can make two inputs like this:

```
<input id="One" readonly />
<input id="Two" required style="display: none" /> //invisible
```

And change the value `Two` to the value that´s inside the input `One`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and finally I use this solution (with jQuery):

```
form.find(':input[required][readonly]').filter(function(){ return this.value === '';})
```

In addition to the form.checkValidity(), I test the length of the above search somehow this way:

```
let fcnt = $(form)
    .find(':input[required][readonly]')
    .filter(function() { return this.value === '';})
    .length;

if (form.checkValidity() && !fcnt) {
   form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["test2"].value;
    if (x == "") {
      alert("Name missing!!");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm" action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text"  name="test1">
    <input type="text" disabled name="test2">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Some explanation to support your answer please. Code only answers are not very educational.

Answer (score -1):

It's the best solution for me. The client can not type anything and must be filled

```
<input type="text" class="read-only" required>
.read-only {
         pointer-events: none;
 }
```