# Parsley.js required attribute not working if field is readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have an input field to enter datetime. I have set its attribute readonly to restrict manual input (as the user might enter date in different format.)

Next, I'm using parsely.js for the form validation. I have added the data-parsley-required attribute to the input field but the required validation doesn't work for this readonly input field.

If I remove the readonly and let only the required attribute stay there, then it works.

How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking. Codepen?

Comment: @Marc: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWLLbJ

Comment: The problem is that I have an input field which I need to keep `readonly` and also want it to be a `required` field. So I have both `readonly` and `required` attributes on the `<input>` tag. But when I do so the `required` doesn't work.

Comment: Surprisingly, this problem doesn't appear in the codepen. I also tried same thing with jsfiddle and it works properly there too. It is only when I try it locally or from the hosted website that this happens.

Comment: Maybe there is an error with the markup on your local instance that is corrected in codepen?  Try html-tidy.

Comment: @J E Carter: Can required and readonly attributes both work simultaneously? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777751/html-required-readonly-input-in-form