# checkValidity on a disabled input always returns true

Tags: javascript, css

I am checking the validity of a required field and it works fine if the field is not disabled. If the input is disabled, it returns true. Is this expected ?

```js
let v1 = $("#i1")[0].checkValidity();
$("#l1")[0].innerHTML = "Validity Before Disabling field:<b>" + v1 + "</b";
$("#i1").prop("readonly", true);
let v2 = $("#i1")[0].checkValidity();
$("#l2")[0].innerHTML = "Validity After  Disabling field:<b>" + v2 + "</b";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    <form>
    Input: <input id="i1" name="i1" required>
    </form>
    <br>
    <label id="l1"></label><br>
    <label id="l2"></label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the the input validity to return the correct value irrespective of whether its disabled or not. The same behavior is also seen if the field is set to readonly.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN documentation, the `required` field is not applied to `read-only` fields:

> Note: The required attribute is not permitted on inputs with the readonly attribute specified.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Answer (score 1):

`required` will not apply to `readonly` or `disabled` fields.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694734/12914833 a workaround is to prevent editing with event listeners. However that answer still shows the caret when you tab focus the input, so I've fixed that. This should act exactly the same as a readonly input.

```js
let v1 = $("#i1")[0].checkValidity();
$("#l1")[0].innerHTML = "Validity Before Disabling field:<b>" + v1 + "</b";

$("#i1").on('keydown paste focus mousedown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode != 9) // ignore tab
        e.preventDefault();
});
$("#i1").css("caret-color","transparent");

let v2 = $("#i1")[0].checkValidity();
$("#l2")[0].innerHTML = "Validity After  Disabling field:<b>" + v2 + "</b";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
    <form>
    Input: <input id="i1" name="i1" required>
    </form>
    <br>
    <label id="l1"></label><br>
    <label id="l2"></label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```